# Array of increasing floats that have unprecise binary representation

Tags: javascript, binary, floating-point

I want a function that creates an array of increasing floats. I run into problems when the incremenent cannot be represented precisely in binary. An example in an increment of 0.1, whose binary representation is infinitely repeating.

```
var incrementalArray = function(start, end, step) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
        // 0.1 cannot be represented precisely in binary
        // not rounding i will cause weird numbers like 0.99999999
        if (step === 0.1) {
            arr.push(i.toFixed(1));
        } else {
            arr.push(i);
        }
    }
    return arr;
};
```

There are two problems with this implementation. **A)** It only covers the case of having an increment of 0.1. Aren't there numerous other magic numbers that have repeating binary representation? **B)** The returned array does not include the end value when the increment is 0.1. However, it does include the end value when the increment is otherwise, making this function unpredictable.

```
incrementalArray(0.0, 3.0, 0.1);
// [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, .... 2.8, 2.9]

incrementalArray(2,10,2);
// [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

How can this function work for all special increments and be predictable?

Comment: There's no way to tell whether the increment is a repeating fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
var incrementalArray = function(start, end, step) {
    var arr = [];
    // convert count to an integer to avoid rounding errors
    var count = +((end - start) / step).toFixed();
    for (var j = 0; j <= count; j++) {
        var i = start + j * step;
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Output: `0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6000000000000001, 0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2000000000000001, 1.3, 1.4000000000000001, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7000000000000001, 1.8, 1.9000000000000001, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3000000000000002, 2.4000000000000003, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8000000000000002, 2.9000000000000003, 3`

If you want the output truncated to the same number of decimals as the input, you can use this:

```
var incrementalArray = function(start, end, step) {
    var prec = ("" + step).length - ("" + step).indexOf(".") - 1;
    var arr = [];
    // convert count to an integer to avoid rounding errors
    var count = +((end - start) / step).toFixed();
    for (var j = 0; j <= count; j++) {
        var i = start + +(j * step).toFixed(prec);
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Output: `0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0`

Comment: Looks like this might work if you truncated the values, but it does still have the weird floating point rounding sometimes

Comment: incrementalArray(0.0, 1.0, 0.00001); produces only 100,000 values, not 100,001.

Comment: Rick Regan: Oops! I fixed it. Thanks for spotting the bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you limit yourself to rational numbers you can express the steps with integers and divide the integer index by a single denominator as you convert each entry to a float (if you have to have it in that form).

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI the problem is actually more complex than you may realize because in the IEEE754 binary floating point representation the number line is not evenly spaced — as the magnitude increases the least-detectable difference (LDD) also increases (i.e., the representable numbers get farther apart).

What this *means* is fairly simple: you can easily call this routine with parameters that will result in an infinite loop if the absolute magnitude of *step* is less than the LDD on the interval bounded by *start* and *end*.

The simplest way I know to determine the least-detectable difference at any arbitrary point in the real number line is this example (with the usual caveats about matching data type sizes) — there is no significance to the value, it was simply a random number:

```
real_32 A = 999.111f;
uint_32 B = (*(uint_32*) &A) ^ 1; //create a 1-bit difference
real_32 LDD = abs(A - *(real_32*) &B);
```

FWIW you can easily use a variant of this mechanism to determine if two real numbers are within the LDD of each other and consider that “equal” since direct comparison of reals is problematic.

Comment: That method isn't going to work so well in JavaScript. Or in C or C++, where it is undefined behavior (and who knows what the optimizer will do to it).

Comment: can't help you with JS, but i've done this exact thing for about 30yrs in C and C++ so i'm not quite sure why you think it's undefined ... every bit of it is based on the ieee754 spec

Comment: It undefined because of the aliasing rules in ISO C99 §6.5. See for example the SO question [What is the strict aliasing rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/27727) … of course, in this case, I doubt any compilers take liberties with it.

Answer (score 0):

How about scaling them up to integers and then back down? ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bemace/JvzWf/1/))

```
function incrementalArray(start, end, step) {
    step += "";
    var scale = Math.pow(10, step.length - step.indexOf(".") - 1);
    start *= scale;
    end *= scale;
    step *= scale;
    var values = new Array();
    for (var x = start; x < end; x += step) {
        values.push(x / scale);
    }

    return values;   
}
```